# Specifying default schema WebSpehere 8.5 Server

Tags: websphere-8

I am working on a migration project where we are migrating one application from Weblogic to Websphere 8.5 server.

In Weblogic server, we can specify default schema while creating datasource but I don't see same option in WebSpehere 8.5 server.

Is there any custom property through which we can set it , I tried currentSchema=MySchema but it did not work.

Comment: We are connecting to Oracle Database

Comment: are you using WebSphere traditional or WebSphere Liberty?

Comment: I am using WebSphere traditional

Comment: How do you do it for Websphere Liberty flavor?

Comment: In Oracle, the schema is associated with the user, at the database administration. When that user connect to base, the associated schema is automatically loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer requires significantly more work, but I'm including it because it's the designed solution to customize pretty much anything about a connection, including the schema.  WebSphere Application Sever allows you to provide/extend a DataStoreHelper.

[Knowledge Center document on providing a custom DataStoreHelper](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5////com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tdat_cusdatstore.html?lang=en)

In this case, you can extend `com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.Oracle11gDataStoreHelper`.

[JavaDoc for Oracle11gDataStoreHelper](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/rsadapter/Oracle11gDataStoreHelper.html)

The following methods will be of interest:

- `doConnectionSetup`, which performs one-time initialization on a connection when it is first created
- `doConnectionCleanup`, which resets connection state before returning it to the connection pool.

When you override `doConnectionSetup`, you are supplied with the newly created connection, upon which you can do,

```
super.doConnectionSetup(connection);
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
try {
    stmt.execute(sqlToUpdateSchema);
} finally {
    stmt.close();
}
```

`doConnectionCleanup` lets you account for the possibility that application code that is using the connection might switch the schema to something else.  `doConnectionCleanup` gives you the opportunity to reset it.  Again, you are supplied with a connection, upon which you can do,

```
super.doConnectionCleanup(connection);
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
try {
    stmt.execute(sqlToUpdateSchema);
} finally {
    stmt.close();
}
```

Note that in both cases, invoking the corresponding super class method is important to ensure you don't wipe out the database-specific initialization/cleanup code that WebSphere Application Server has built in based on the database.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Weblogic only allows setting a default schema by setting the 'Init SQL`to a SQL string which sets the current schema in the database, such as`SQL ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=MySchema`.  So, this answer is assuming the only way to set the current schema of a data source is via SQL.

In WebSphere, the closest thing to WebLogic's `Init SQL` is the `preTestSQLString` property on WebSphere.

The idea of the `preTestSQLString` property is that WebSphere will execute a very simple SQL statement to verify that you can connect to your database properly when the server is starting.  Typically values for this property are really basic things like `select 1 from dual', but since you can put in whatever SQL you want, you could set`preTestSQLString`to`SQL ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=MySchema`.

Steps from the WebSphere documentation ([link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21439688)):

> 1. In the administrative console, click Resources > JDBC providers.
> 2. Select a provider and click Data Sources under Additional properties.
> 3. Select a data source and click WebSphere Application Server data source properties under Additional properties.
> 4. Select the PreTest Connections check box.
> 5. Type a value for the PreTest Connection Retry Interval, which is measured in seconds. This property determines the frequency with which a new connection request is made after a pretest operation fails.
> 6. Type a valid SQL statement for the PreTest SQL String. Use a reliable SQL command, with minimal performance impact; this statement is processed each time a connection is obtained from the free pool.
>      For example, "select 1 from dual" in oracle or "SQL select 1" in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Universal Connection Pool (UCP) is a Java connection pool and the whitepaper "[UCP with Webshere"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/planned-unplanned-rlb-ucp-websphere-2409214.pdf) shows how to set up UCP as a datasource.

for JDBC datasource, the steps are similar but, you can choose the default JDBC driver option.

Check out the paper for reference.